# split DataTemplate in different grids using ItemTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I am working on WPF-XAML. My requirement is : 
I need to add collection of Trunks(which consists of Border & TexBlocks) in a Tab.
there will be 2 types of such Trunks (say **RSPTrunkTemplate** and **ASPTrunkTemplate**). now I need to add collection of Trunks of type **RSPTrunkTemplate** in one grid. then there will be GridSplitter and then I need to add another collection of Trunks of type **ASPTrunkTemplate** in another grid.

I am using ItemTemplateSelector as follows :

```
<Grid>
                <ItemsControl Name="TrunkList"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding RSPTrunks}"
                              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TrunkItemTemplateSelector}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
```

this TrunkItemTemplateSelector is as follows :

```
<Helpers:TrunkItemTemplateSelector x:Key="TrunkItemTemplateSelector"
                                           RSPTrunkTemplate="{StaticResource RSPTrunkTemplate}"
                                           SPTrunkTemplate="{StaticResource ASPTrunkTemplate}" />
```

Now, **RSPTrunkTemplate** should be in one grid and **ASPTrunkTemplate** shoulb be in another grid.
How to do this. Do I have to change my approach.?
I seek your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

ItemTemplateSelector, as the name suggests, is used to specify a different template for the objects inside a ItemsControl, not to do filtering. If i understand correctly you want to apply a grouping maybe this link can help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742542.aspx